# Selecting range in a data.frame containing of factors

Tags: r, range

If i have a data.frame like this, but much bigger

```
> df
#     df 
#  1  G0100
#  2  G0546
#  3  G1573
#  4  G1748
#  5  G2214
#  6  G2473
#  7  G2764
#  8  G3421
#  9  G5748
#  10 G8943
```

is there a beautiful way to select a range between G1500 and G2500 in much bigger data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `parse_number` with `between`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>%
  filter(between(parse_number(df), 1500, 2500))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not really clear from the question what the general case is but we provide a variety of solutions based on different assumptions.

**1)** Assuming

- the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end
- the lower and upper bounds are both 5 characters, as in the question

then use `subset` as shown.  If all values in the data frame are 5 characters the first condition could be omitted.

```
subset(df, nchar(df) == 5 & df >= "G1500" & df <= "G2500")
```

giving:

```
     df
3 G1573
4 G1748
5 G2214
6 G2473
```

**2)** Another possibility which relaxes the second assumption above is the following which gives the same output as above.  The second argument of `strapply` is a function given in formula notation.  x is the first argument corresponding to the first capture group and y is the second argument corresponding to the second capture group.

```
library(gsubfn)
subset(df, strapply(df, "(.)(.*)", 
   ~ x=='G' & as.numeric(y) >= 1500 & as.numeric(y) <= 2500, 
   simplify = TRUE))
```

**3)** If every entry in the data frame begins with G or if we can ignore the letter then we could just omit it.

```
num <- as.numeric(sub("G", "", df$df))
subset(df, num >= 1500 & num <= 2500)
```

**4)** Another variation to read the first character and the rest into separate columns of a new data frame DF and then use subset:

```
DF <- read.table(text = sub("(.)", "\\1 ", df$df))
subset(df, DF$V1 == "G" & DF$V2 >= 1500 & DF$V2 <= 2500)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
        df 
  1  G0100
  2  G0546
  3  G1573
  4  G1748
  5  G2214
  6  G2473
  7  G2764
  8  G3421
  9  G5748
  10 G8943"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[between(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df)), 1500, 2500)]]
      df
1: G1573
2: G1748
3: G2214
4: G2473
```

Comment: Somehow I would have expected a base R answer from you, esp. since here the `data.table` solution seems to be even slower... Maybe something like `df[{a=as.numeric(substring(df$df, 2)); a >=1500 & a <=2500},, drop=FALSE]`. I have to say, though, that the readr solution seems to be the most efficient one in this case.

Comment: @user12728748 Yes, `readr` is more efficient